# Upgrading Android from 4.2 to 4.4 on Lenovo Tablet B6000-HV

Tags: updates, tablet, lenovo

I have tried and failed to upgrade from Android 4.2 to 4.4 on my Lenovo B6000-HV. At first using OTA method; Error in the middle of process and I have to flash with stock ROM to make it working again. Then I tried to put the files on micro SDcard; The error was `failed to update`.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**:

Go to Recovery and Clear cache and Dalvik.

Reboot and Check for OTA.

Update it.

**Method 2**:

**Backup all data** to any external storage (Apps and data).

Factory Reset device.

Check for OTA.

Update it.

**Restore Data**.

**Method 3**:

Install Custom Recovery and Custom Kitkat ROM from XDA.

[Custom Recovery](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2611077)

[Custom ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2791072&page=2)